# Android HttpResponse - Content has been consumed

Tags: android, httpresponse

The method below falls over when reading the HttpResponse with the error: "Content has been  consumed". I understand that the content can only be consumed once but I get this error on the very first attempt and I don't see anywhere in the code where I'm possibly consuming it twice.

```
    private static String getData(String url, HttpParams params) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        if (params != null) {
            httpGet.setParams(params);
        }
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                content.close();
                result = builder.toString();
            } 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return result;  
    }
```

Comment: are you sure exception is being generated into only this block of code

Comment: What is the result of calling `isStreaming` on your response entity?

Comment: Put a few logs in the various blocks and check if something is being called twice. If that doesn't help, provide the code where you are calling it and also the logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this in the emulator or on your phone? It could be an emulator specific problem. I've test it on my device, and it works perfectly.

Do you perhaps have a debugger watch that could be consuming the content?

Comment: I've upgraded everything to the latest (ADT, SDK) and it still gives problems on both my phone in debug mode and on the emulator.

Comment: That was it - thanks! I had a watch on entity.getContent(). Removed the watch and everything is working 100%.

Comment: i had the same case, watch was set on entity.getcontent() removing watch resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

make sure that you don't have in the Eclipse watch view something like  **http_response.getEntity()**
If you do, then this is what consumes your stream...

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you're consuming the entity more than once, in a similar call to this:

```
EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your get Data() method is perfect and it's working fine i already used this code to check and it's working perfectly for me.

so might there is a possibility that you called this method twice. if you want to check what i m using check below code i get result perfectly.

```
package com.sandeeppatel.httpget;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HttpGetActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.vogella.com");
    /*if (params != null) {
        httpGet.setParams(params);
    }*/
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            content.close();
            result = builder.toString();
        } 
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 // return result;  
}
}
```

And just i m giving the Internet permission only.
Still if you not getting this give me your url and params.

Comment: That's what I thought. The code runs 100% fine on a colleagues pc but with me it gives "content has been consumed" on both my emulator and on my phone in debug mode. I upgraded the ADT and SDK just to be sure but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is right. but try this to access string from HttpEntity:
    String response_str =EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

like i used in my method:

```
    public String SetObjectSecurity(String username, String password,
        String clientName,String docRid,String ObjectRidsForCheckSum) throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    String SetObjectSecurityURL = "url";
    StringEntity str_request_entity = null;
    HttpResponse http_response = null;

    HttpGet getrequest = new HttpGet(SetObjectSecurityURL);
    postrequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    postrequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//set param here


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    http_response = httpClient.execute(getrequest);

    //Log.e("Status code ",http_response);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = http_response.getEntity();

    String response_str =EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
    Log.e("output",response_str);
    int i = http_response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.e("status","code "+i);


if(i==this){

do this}
else
{
this
}       
        return response_str;
        }
```