# Http request with arry object

Tags: android, http

making request in `AsynckTask` using `NameValuePair` but not getting response

```
try
                {  
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

                    System.out.println(operation);
                    post = new HttpPost(operation);
                    if(nvp != null)
                    {
                        String temp = "dgdfg";
                        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                    }
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    entity = response.getEntity();
                    if(entity != null)
                    {
                        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Response Failed","Response from server is failed");
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Url

```
String url = "http://www.xxx.com/service/xxx.asmx/xxxxMethodName";
```

request parametres like

```
{
    UserDetails =     {
        DeviceName = "My Phone";
        DeviceToken = 707fc5a77124dd1a485608e8e03d31b708a0359b852df38bb3cc856e28;
        EmailAddress = "admin@xxx.com";
        IsRemember = True;
        Password = "admin@xxx.com";
    };
}
```

in numvalues need like

```
 String mm = "{ UserDetails = {DeviceName=\"My Phone\"; DeviceToken = 707fc5a77124dd1a485608e8e03d31b708a0359b852df38bb3cc856e28;EmailAddress=\"admin@xxx.com\";IsRemember = True; Password = \"admin@xxx.com\";  };}";
```

but not getting here i m getting  [...]

Comment: Ankit Never use actual web service on the SO. And by the way Web services are only for app and if anyone find your actual WS URL than it will be risky.

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
public static String doPost(String mUrl, ArrayList<String[]> ArrayStr,
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient) {

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(mUrl);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String DataTest = "";

        //creating name value pair
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayStr.size(); i++) {
            DataTest += " ITem -" + ArrayStr.get(i)[0] + ":  Value -"
                    + ArrayStr.get(i)[1];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(ArrayStr.get(i)[0],
                    ArrayStr.get(i)[1]));
        }
        //adding values with postmethod
        try {
            System.out.println("Request - >>" + DataTest);
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
            response.toString();



        //  System.out.println("Response - >>" + str);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
        return inputSteamToString(inputStream);

    }
//to convert response to string

public static String inputSteamToString(InputStream is) {

        StringBuffer responseInBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] b = new byte[4028];
        try {
            for (int n; (n = is.read(b)) != -1;) {
                responseInBuffer.append(new String(b, 0, n));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response=new String(responseInBuffer.toString());
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: pls check my request parameter its not only array so getting isssue

Comment: i check your service...it's work ...but it gives null at response.getEntity().getContent().. please remove this & work...for more refrensce take a look to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168617/android-httpresponse-content-has-been-consumed

Comment: comment this line in my code inputStream=response.getEntity().getContent(); and place a log statement. EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); it give some response regarding your service url...i think u should look on it...it gives you some help to sovle this problem

Comment: hey dude your service is url is wrong. it would be..
 String URL="http://www.swipealert.com/service/swipealert.asmx?op=MemberSelectByEmailAndPassword";

and remainning work is same as till previous comment...